# Security Concerns when passing php variables to json on page

Tags: javascript, json, security, vue.js

I'm beginning to implement Vue bindings in my site and realize I'll need to render variables into a json array within my DOM, visible to all to view.

Fortunately the objects will be session and permission based, so the content will only be available to people who own the data (ie a user can see their user and account information in a json object), but seems to expose some of my logic and data structure and my instinct raises security concerns.

Does anyone have security concerns with passing the content in a json object or best practice they follow when preparing their json to abstract some of the data?

In reviewing most of the major sites I've seen most of them now provide the data in a json object available for me to view.  I've been using this to analyze how they abstract some of the data, but any good references would be greatly appreciated.

Here is an example json object I'd expose in my html. Please feel free to critique and offer feedback on what you'd be hesitant exposing.

```
window.example = {
 "id":52,
 "account_id":1,
 "name":"Account Owner",
 "business_name":"Example fishing supplies",
 "website":"http:\/\/www.example.com",
 "type_id":3,
 "is_active":1,
 "logo_image":"example-logo-image.png",
 "header_image":"example-header-image.jpg",
 "favicon":"example-favicon.png",
 "email":"example@example.com",
 "first_name":"example",
 "last_name":"smith",
 "handle":"example",
 "phone":"+12223331234",
 "address_id":23,
 "street_address":
 "226 Example Drive",
 "street_address_2":" ",
 "city":"Example",
 "state":"Example",
 "country":"United States",
 "postal_code":"12345",
 "accessed_date":"2018-07-01 18:13:46"
}
```

Comment: I've heard that N26 once had security issues because they exposed too much data in their json interfaces, data which was used in security questions for example.

Comment: https://youtu.be/KopWe2ZpVQI?t=22m13s The bottom line is, you might not want to expose too much stuff, just in case a session does get hijacked or somehow someone gets unwanted access to your data.